# Checking if folder exist using case/switch

Tags: shell-script, files

Is it possible to use case to check if folders exist?

I have these folders. I need to check if they exist then do something afterwards, I have 5 folders I need to check, and if it does exist, I process something different in each of the folders. Can it be done?

If not, what is the best way for that? perhaps a multiple if statements?

Answer (score 3):

Case statements don't have the ability to perform evaluations of conditionals in the same way that if/then's can. A case/switch can really only match patterns, and execute specific cases, based on the match.

#### Potential solutions

I'd start with using `[ .. ]` like this.

```
[ -d /path/to/folder1 ] && echo cmd1
[ -d /path/to/folder2 ] && echo cmd2
[ -d /path/to/folder3 ] && echo cmd3
[ -d /path/to/folder4 ] && echo cmd4
[ -d /path/to/folder5 ] && echo cmd5
```

If you need to do more elaborate commands afterwards then you might want to switch to a formal if/then.

```
if [ -d /path/to/folder1 ]; then
  cmd1;
fi
```

Answer (score 0):

Of course you can do that using a mix of globs/case.

For a single folder you do like this:

```
set X "$folder_name" "${folder_name}"*/; shift
case $2 in
   "$1/" ) echo "The folder <<${folder_name}>> exists." ;;
   * ) echo "The folder <<${folder_name}>> does not exist." ;;
esac
```